# How to model a class that descends from two potential classes

Tags: delphi, uml

I am writing an accounting application and am unclear how to model a vendor.  In my business domain, a vendor is defined as a person or a business who sells products or provides services.  The main difference between a person and a business is the person has a first, middle and last name, whereas the business has just a name.

It would seem a vendor should descend from both, but Delphi, my programming language, does not permit multiple inheritance.  Is there a way to create an either/or inheritance relationship or do I include each of the name attributes in my model and a "type" attribute that would take values of "person, business"?

Comment: How about define vendor as parent class that holds common properties or methods for both (eg: display name, address, etc.) and two classes for each business and person that holds its unique properties as child class?

Comment: This question makes me think of this video, "Composition over Inheritance" https://youtu.be/wfMtDGfHWpA

Comment: Try to stop using inheritance

Comment: David, How do you recommend I do that in this instance?

Answer (score 1):

If you say that a `Person` is *always* a kind of `Vendor` and a `Business` is *always* a kind of `Vendor`, you can never have an instance of `Person` that is not also an instance of `Vendor`, and you can never have an instance of `Business` that is not also an instance of `Vendor`. That doesn't work.

Let's try to invert the hierarchy. If you say that a `Vendor` is *always* a kind of `Person` *and* a `Business`, an instance of `Vendor` cannot exist without also being *both* a `Person` and a `Business`. That doesn't work either.

Something is wrong here!

Enter *roles*. In general, a `Role` is played by an `Actor`. In your case, an `Actor` can be a `Person` or a `Business`. A `Vendor` is a `Role` played by one of those `Actors`. Heck, you could even make the two subclasses of `Actors` *covering* and *disjoint*, meaning that you cannot have an instance of `Actor` that is not also an instance of `Person` or a `Vendor`, and that an instance cannot be both a `Person` *and* a `Vendor`.

Roles give you a lot of flexibility. For example, you can have a `Person` who plays the role of a different `Vendor` with respect to two different different `Buyers`. Roles can also come and go, with start and end times. Thus, I think a **role** is the solution you're looking for.